# API instead of BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, api, beautifulsoup

This document defines some URL's and IP's of MS services:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/urls-and-ip-address-ranges?view=o365-worldwide#exchange-online

My goal is to write a Python script that check what is the last updated date of this document.
If the date is change (means that some IP's changed), I need to know it immediately. I can't found any API for this goal, so I wrote this script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
import re

url = "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/urls-and-ip-address-ranges?view=o365-worldwide#exchange-online"

#set the headers as a browser
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

while True:
    response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html.parser")
    last_update_fra = soup.find(string=re.compile("01/04/2021"))
    time.sleep(60)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text, "html.parser")
    if soup.find(string=re.compile("01/04/2021")) == last_update_fra:
        print(last_update_fra)
        continue
    else:
        #send an email for notification
        pass
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it. since if the date will change, I also need to update my script to another date (the updated date).
In addition, this is ok to do it with BeautifulSoup? or there's another and a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Beautifulsoup is fine here. I don't even see an XHR request with the data anayway there.

Couple things I noted:

1. Do you really want/need it checked every minute? Maybe better every day/24 hours, or ever 12 or 6 hours?
2. If at any point it crashes, Ie you lose internet connection or get a 400 response, you'll need to restart the script and lose whatever the last date was. So maybe consider a) writing the date to disk somewhere so it's not just stored in memory, and b) put in some try/exceptions in there so that if it does encounter an error, it'll keep running and just try again at the next interval (or how ever you decide it to try again).

**Code:**

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/urls-and-ip-address-ranges?view=o365-worldwide#exchange-online'

#set the headers as a browser
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

last_update_fra = ''
while True:
    time.sleep(60)
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    found_date = soup.find('time').text
    if found_date == last_update_fra:    
        print(last_update_fra)
        continue
    else:
        # store new date
        last_update_fra = found_date
        
        #send an email for notification
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
A question regarding the: found_date = soup.find('time').text
How it is know to grab this specific date?